# What are the .map files in the angularjs .zip file?

Tags: angularjs

I just downloaded angularjs 1.2 rc1, and there are a bunch of .map files, I have no idea what they are, it's a JSON file, but for what are they used?

Answer (score 0):

Bah, they are source maps. Less ask, more thinky.